# XML Mapping Tool Delphi Tokyo

Tags: delphi, xml

Gostaria de saber qual a forma correta de mapear um .XML pelo *Delphi Tokyo* com o xml mapping tool e ler no `ClientDataSet`.

Utilizando o *XML Mapping Tool* com o *Delphi 7* consigo fazer o mapeamento e ler os arquivos pelo `ClientDataSet` sem problema.

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
     begin
         XMLTransform1.SourceXmlFile:= OpenDialog1.FileName;
         XMLTransform1.TransformationFile:= ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+ 'transformation.xtr';
         Cds_Fornecedor.XMLData:= XMLTransform1.Data;
     end;
```

Quando passa pela linha:

> Cds_Fornecedor.XMLData:= XMLTransform1.Data;

Retorna o seguinte erro:

> XML PARSE ERROR: 
>   Reason: O Sistema não pode localizar o objeto especificado.

Obs.: Gerei o schema.xml e o .xtr pelo Delphi 7 e depois gerei pelo Delphi Tokyo

Answer (score 0):

Li um artigo na net que o programador usava o `XMLTransformProvider` no *Delphi Tokyo* ao invés de usar o `XMLTransform` (igual ao *Delphi 7*). Então mudei o componente e o código ficou assim:

```
 If ClientDataSet1.Active then
    ClientDataSet1.Close;
 ClientDataSet1.providerName:= 'XMLTransformProvider1';

 XMLTransformProvider1.TransformRead.TransformationFile:= 'arquivo.xtr'
 XMLTransformProvider1.XMLDataFile:= OpenDialog1.FileName;
 ClientDataSet1.Active:= True;
```

Preferi responder a minha própria pergunta ao invés de apagá-la, pois sei que se eu tive essa dificuldade, com certeza, outra pessoa também terá.